# Strange WHERE statement that behaves like a GROUP BY?

Tags: sql

I've come across a simple SQL query that should return a single row, but instead returns results like a GROUP BY statement.

Here is the query:

```
select
  column_a,
  column_b
from table_1 A1
  where column_b = (
    select MIN(column_b)
    from table_1 A2
    where A1.column_a = A2.column_a
    )
;
```

And here is a table_1, the only table the query uses:

```
column_a column_b
a 3
a 2
a 1
b 5
b 4
c 6
```

**The strange thing is that the query should only return a single row, column_a = "a" and column_b = "1", because the subquery will evaluate to "1".**

But the actual result is the minimum for each letter in column_a. So:

```
a 1
b 4
c 6
```

Can anyone help me understand why the query is behaving like this?

I've setup a SQL Fiddle page with the example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b4d6f/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *(correlation clause*:

```
where column_b = (select MIN(column_b)
                  from table_1 A2
                  where A1.column_a = A2.column_a
------------------------^
                  )
```

It connects the subquery to the outer query.  You can think of this as looping through the table in the outer row and keeping the row *only* when `column_b` has the minimum `column_b` value *for the `column_a` value*.  Note that the query may not be executed by using such a nested loop!

If you wanted the overall minimum, you would leave out the correlation clause:

```
where column_b = (select MIN(column_b)
                  from table_1 A2
                  )
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a correlated subquery, it filters using the value of `A1.column_a`. That means for each different value of `column_a` you will get a (potentially) different result.

This is why it looks like it is grouping by `column_a`.

You should also note that because you are not grouping you could get duplicate rows where there exist ties for the minimum `column_b` for a value of `column_a`